# Android Compose scroll up after focus on BasicTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I'm using BasicTextField to stylize my text input field. I'm having a problem where when I focus on said text input on the lower part of the screen, keyboard overlaps my input a bit. Is there a way to fix it ? Here's my BasicTextField

```
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .heightIn(min = 68.dp)
            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Blue)
            .background(color = Color.White),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset(y = (8).dp)
                .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 20.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
                .weight(1f),
            textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 24.sp, lineHeight = 37.sp),
            maxLines = 5,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
            value = input,
            onValueChange = {
                input = it
            },
            decorationBox = {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.offset(y = (-16).dp),
                    text = "amount",
                    fontSize = 12.sp,
                    color = Color.Gray,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
                it()
            },
        )
        Row(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 4.dp, end = 16.dp),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.arrow_down),
                contentDescription = null,
                colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color = Color.Blue)
            )
        }
    }
```

[image]

I tried adding specific height on BasicTextField, removing border and background from Row and adding to BasicTextField, but end result wasn't the text field looking like I want it to. I also need the text field to be able to expand on break line and that's where a lot of times it went bad when trying to adjust it. Maybe I'm missing something.